# Avoid division by zero in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, aggregate-functions, divide-by-zero

I'd like to perform division in a SELECT clause. When I join some tables and use aggregate function I often have either null or zero values as the dividers. As for now I only come up with this method of avoiding the division by zero and null values.

```
(CASE(COALESCE(COUNT(column_name),1)) WHEN 0 THEN 1
ELSE (COALESCE(COUNT(column_name),1)) END)
```

I wonder if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Division by a null value is not a problem in the way that division by zero is.

By the way, count() never returns null.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Since **`count()` never returns `NULL`** (unlike other aggregate functions), you only have to catch the `0` case (which is the only problematic case anyway). So, your query simplified:

```
CASE count(column_name)
   WHEN 0 THEN 1
   ELSE count(column_name)
END
```

Or simpler, yet, with `NULLIF()`, [like Yuriy provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681467/939860).

[Quoting the manual about aggregate functions:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

> It should be noted that except for `count`, these functions return a
> null value when no rows are selected.

Answer (score 376):

You can use [NULLIF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) function e.g.

```
something/NULLIF(column_name,0)
```

If the value of `column_name` is 0 - result of entire expression will be NULL

Comment: something like value/COALESCE(NULLIF(column_name,0), 1) would work I suppose

Comment: Tried it with COALESCE as @Akash suggested and it did the work

Comment: This is the perfectly semantic solution to many division by zero problems! Sometimes you don't want the division to be some other value, you want it not to be computed at all!

Answer (score 62):

I realize this is an old question, but another solution would be to make use of the *greatest* function:

```
greatest( count(column_name), 1 )  -- NULL and 0 are valid argument values
```

---

***Note:***
My preference would be to either return a NULL, as in Erwin and Yuriy's answer, or to solve this logically by detecting the value is `0` before the division operation, and returning `0`.  Otherwise, the data may be misrepresented by using `1`.

Comment: I'm going to use this, since my divisor is an "elapsed time" for a process, and 0 probably means a fraction of a second, so I'll use 0.01 minutes as a default time. I'm only comparing process performance.

Comment: This was the simplest solution to me, in terms of readability

Comment: I do think more people need to read your note.  I've come across some code which put in place variants of the solutions presented here without further thought, and dividing by 1 has very significant implications for certain contexts.  Even the original question could have been frame challenged since it's almost certain their application shouldn't have been receiving a `count / 1` output when the denominator had no results.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution avoiding division by zero, replacing to **1**

```
select column + (column = 0)::integer;
```

Comment: This is really clever.

Comment: Worked for me! can you please explain what it does?

Comment: I believe `(column = 0)` returns a boolean. When a boolean is cast to an integer, `TRUE` becomes `1` and FALSE becomes `0`. So When column=0, this returns 1, NULL returns NULL, 1 returns 1, any other int returns itself. Casting is usually slow, and this code is really hard to understand though.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the divider to be 1 when the count is zero:

```
count(column_name) + 1 * (count(column_name) = 0)::integer
```

The cast from `true` to `integer` is 1.

Comment: Nice trick, but I think that a case statement might be more obvious.

Comment: `CASE` is also faster, even if more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I did the below as suggested and it worked

`column_name / COALESCE(NULLIF(column_name,0), 1)`

Even a `sum` function can work like below:

```
 (
sum(column_name) :: decimal / COALESCE(
  NULLIF(sum(other_column_name) :: decimal, 0),1) :: decimal * 100
)
```