# generated column not producing expected results

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to add a generated column to a postgresql table. It's a percentage derived from two other columns. To avoid division by zero errors I've used the method outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681467/11192010).

```
ALTER TABLE passing 
ADD COLUMN pass_completion DECIMAL(4,1) 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cmp_pass / coalesce(nullif(att_pass,0),1) * 100) STORED;
```

The resulting column output is always `0.0` so something has gone wrong.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Add `1.0 * ` to coerce non-integer arithmetic:  `. . . generated always as (1.0 * cmp_pass / coalesce(nullif(att_pass,0),1) * 100)`   You could also change the 100 to 100.0.

Comment: Consider using a view instead of a generated column.