# Showing milestone percentages for each milestone while aggregating

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, math, amazon-athena, division

I have a query, whose the output is the following:

| Milestone | Counts | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Entrance | 100 | 01 |
| Lunch | 50 | 02 |
| Closings | 25 | 03 |

The query is like so

```
SELECT CASE WHEN groupname = 'Entrance' THEN '01'
            WHEN groupname = 'Lunch'    THEN '02' 
            WHEN groupname = 'Closings' THEN '03' END AS "MilestoneOrder"
      ,groupname AS "Milestone"
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT personid) AS "Counts"
FROM PersonCounts
WHERE DateComparison IN('firstenterbeforetransact', 'firstentersamedayastransact')
GROUP BY groupname
ORDER BY MilestoneOrder
```

I want to try to add a line in my code which will help show the Milestone Percentages for each milestone. For example: Entrance % would be 100/100 = 100%, Entrance -> Lunch would be 50/100 = 50%, and lastly Entrance -> Closings would be 25/100 = 25%. I am struggling to figure this calculation out.

I tried adding this line here, but I kept getting an error:

```
`,COUNT(DISTINCT personid) / COUNT(lpersonid WHERE groupname = 'Entrance') AS "ConversionPercentage"
```

Comment: Try with `COUNT(lpersonid) FILTER(WHERE groupname = 'Entrance')`.

Comment: Like this? 
'COUNT(DISTINCT lpersonid) AS "People"
,COUNT(DISTINT lpersonid) / COUNT(lpersonid) FILTER(WHERE groupname = 'Entrance')'

I got an error when I tried it DIVISION_BY_ZERO as the error

Comment: [Avoid division by zero in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681375/avoid-division-by-zero-in-postgresql)

Comment: Can you update your post with some sample data, taken from your real data, that give you that issue, and corresponding expected output?